# Calling the constructor containing the list

Tags: android, constructor

This is my class having construtor as:

```
  public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList;
    private Context context;
    private String expandableListTitile;
    private ArrayList<String> expandableListDetail;

public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListItemList = expandableListItemList;

}}
```

I have called it on another class as:

```
CustomExpandableListAdapter expandableListadapter;
```

and Oncreate i have initialized it as:

```
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListDetail);
```

This is my expandablelist item class

```
public class ExpandableListItem {
    public static final int CHILD_TYPE_EDITTEXT = 0;
    public static final int CHILD_TYPE_TEXT_FIELD = 1;
    public static final int CHILD_TYPE_RADIO_BUTTON = 2;
    public static final int CHILD_TYPE_CHECKBOX = 3;

    private List<String> childLabels;
    private String title;
    private int selectionType;

    public List<String> getChildLabels() {
        return childLabels;
    }

    public void setChildLabels(List<String> childLabels) {
        this.childLabels = childLabels;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getSelectionType() {
        return selectionType;
    }

    public void setSelectionType(int selectionType) {
        this.selectionType = selectionType;
    }
}
```

But i am unable to call the constructor. Please help it out.

Comment: any error log got ?

Comment: make sure you are sending a `List<>` and not an `ArrayList<>` as the constructor expects a `List<>`

Comment: no error log. Red line appears while calling the constructor

Comment: @AmanGrover in the adapter class i have implemented ExpandableListItem inside the List.nd how can i call the constructor?

Comment: Is "expandableListAdapter" in your onCreate method typed as a CustomExpandableListAdapter object?

Comment: yes expandableLIstAdapter is the object of the CustomExpandableListAdapter @RustWebDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while calling your adapter constructor pass parameters as context and your List objects like this.

```
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListDetail); // here expandableListDetail item is your List<ExpandableListItem>
```

Comment: How to add the parameters of this adapter class while caling this parameter into next class.?

Comment: I am ok with adapter class.

Comment: You want to set data after change in list ..?

Comment: till now i want to call this constructor from another class

Comment: yes please post your code for activity class file. Where  you are calling adapter

Comment: i have creater the object of adapter as :
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, what should be herel);

Comment: there should be List of expandableListItemList items

Comment: So i need to create the object of ExpandableListItems in the class to call the crunstructor?

Comment: can you correct your answer so that i can mark it up :)

Comment: i mean the code for how we have called the constructor from another class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try set data after initialized object then try this in adapter class

```
 public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList;
    private Context context;
    private String expandableListTitile;
    private ArrayList<String> expandableListDetail;

public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListItemList = expandableListItemList;

}}

public setData(List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList){
  this.expandableListItemList = expandableListItemList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: and how can i call this   public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListItemList = expandableListItemList;

}} in another class?

Answer (score 1):

```
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListDetail);
```

here, i don't know in which class you have Oncreate method but suppose it's MainActivity than write MainActivity.this instad of this
and one more thing is expandableListDetail is ArrayList()<>, if you prefer `List<>` then use `AddAll()` method of ArrayList...(ex: ArrayList()<> alt=new ArrayList()<>;
alt.AddAll(list<>);)

so now your code is

```
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, expandableListDetail);
```

make sure that `expandableListDetail` is `ArrayList`, because it's just type mismatch nothing else

Answer (score 0):

When you initialized adapter constructor is automatically called. See this for more info:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ExpandableListItem implement Serializable {
```